# Extension of the solution

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $H \in C[\mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}]$ and $H(x) \to \infty$ as $|x | \to \infty$. Suppose $f \in C[\mathbb{R}_{+} \times \mathbb{R}^{n}, \mathbb{R}^{n}]$ and for some $M >0$:

$$
\frac{\partial H}{\partial x} \cdot f(t,x) \leq 0, \quad |x| \geq M, t\in \mathbb{R}_{+} =[0, \infty)
$$

Show that the solutions of ODE: $x' = f(t,x), x(t_{0}) = x_{0}$ exists on $[t_{0}, \infty)$.

My attempt is that I am trying to prove that $f(t,x)$ is bounded on the right maximal interval of existence. Using the integration-formula

$$
x(t) = x_0 + \int_{t_0}^{t} f(w,x(w)) dw
$$
to derive that $x(t)$ is bounded on the maximal interval.

However, I was stuck using the assumption on $H(x)$. I appreciate any help how to prove this.

Answer (score 1):

Show that:

- $t\mapsto H(x(t))$ is a non-increasing function.
- $H$ has bounded level sets.

Generally, look up "Lyapunov functionals".